# How to replace all instances of text between two characters in a huge JSON string using T-SQL in an Azure SQL database?

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

How to replace text between 2 characters MULTIPLE TIMES in a huge string (50,000 characters) in T-SQL?

I have a JSON output from my Azure Pipeline which we drop into a single cell in a table ready for the stored procedure to parse and process the data.  However, one of the lines in the JSON looks like this

```
"body":"bxncucbuc "what is happening" cbibciuc",
"subject:"whatever" etc etc. .........  
"body":"bxncucbuc "what more things are happening" cbibciuc",
"subject:"whatever" etc etc. .........
"body":"bxncucbuc "what else is happening" cbibciuc",
"subject:"whatever" etc etc.
```

The `openjson` cannot parse the script as the "what is happening" (or similar) looks like another column as it has the " 's in.  So, I am looking to replace everything BETWEEN "body":" and "subject":, as actually I don't need this data anyway.

I can get a single instance replaced using

```
select   
    stuff(jsonresponse, CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse), CHARINDEX('"subject":', jsonresponse) - CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse) + 1, '"bodyX":"replaced with a random piece of text","')
from 
    stage.JsonResponse
```

However

```
while (select CHARINDEX('"body":"<', jsonresponse) from stage.JsonResponse) != 0
begin 
    update stage.JsonResponse 
    set JsonResponse =  stuff(jsonresponse, CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse), CHARINDEX('"subject":', jsonresponse) - CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse) + 1, '"bodyX":"replaced with a random piece of text","')
    from stage.Mimecast_JsonResponse

    if (select CHARINDEX('"body":"<', jsonresponse) 
        from stage.JsonResponse) = 0
        BREAK
    else
        CONTINUE
END
```

just runs forever. I have changed it to look for "body":"< in case it was inadvertently changing some script and then looking for itself, and changing that again etc.

Similarly, I have tried a CTE:

```
;WITH Cte(jsonresponse) AS 
(
    SELECT jsonresponse FROM #a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STUFF(jsonresponse, CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse), CHARINDEX('"subject":"', jsonresponse) - CHARINDEX('"body":"', jsonresponse) + 1, '"body":"replaced with a random piece of text","')
    FROM Cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX('"body":"<', jsonresponse) != 0
)
SELECT jsonresponse 
FROM Cte
WHERE CHARINDEX('"body":"<', jsonresponse) = 0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); `
```

but this too seems to run and run, but actually only changes the first instance.

My JSON is 50,000 characters long, and there are multiple instances in the json that I need to replace ALL OF THEM, and this is where I have struggled, how to change EVERY INSTANCE of the offending script.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am using T-SQL on an Azure SQL database.

Comment: I appreciate this isn't answering your question, but.... If you can dump your JSON into a SQL table, could you dump the JSON file to another storage system (BLOB Container?) where you can just read the JSON file? You've got all the overhead of SQL without any of the benefits by putting the data into one cell.

Comment: The other option is to use [ISJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) before you insert your data. That way you should be able to use `OPENJSON`

Comment: Thankyou @PGHE for your consideration, certainly that could have been an option for us - good suggestion.  Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the option of using a recursive CTE, I believe this should work - I did some experimenting and it appears (probably due to how the data gets amended and referenced or passed around internally) the most reliable way is to *not* affect the length of the string but just to replace characters in-situ.

The following example works to find the sections between each body/subject element and replaces the content with a single repeating character without changing the length.

Since you don't need this content anyway you can then use *replace* to remove it completely.

Does this help for your scenario?

Demo [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dNLyM9cR)

```
with p as (
  select Id, jsonCol,
    CharIndex('"body"', jsonCol) as Bpos,
    CharIndex('"subject"', jsonCol) as Spos
  from t
  union all
  select Id, j,
    CharIndex('"body"', j, Spos) as Bpos,
    CharIndex('"subject"', j, Spos + 1) as Spos
  from p
  cross apply(values( Stuff(jsoncol, bpos + 8, spos - bpos - 10, Replicate('#', spos - bpos - 10))))n(j)
  where Bpos > 0 
)
select Replace(jsoncol, '#','')
from p
where bpos = 0;
```

Comment: Thankyou @Stu this works awesomely, and is so fast on my dataset.  This is an awesome script.  Really appreciate the efforts.